# get string between stopwords in an (time)effective way

Tags: python, performance, loops, substring, list-comprehension

assuming I have a text:

```
txt='A single house painted white with a few windows and a nice door in front of the park'
```

I would like to eliminate all the first words if they are stopwords and get the substring up to the first stop word.

desired outcome: **single house painted white**

I can loop over the list:

```
txt='A single house painted white with a few windows and a nice door in front of the park'
stopwords = ['a','the','with','this','is','to','etc'] # up to 250 words


for i,word in enumerate(txt.lower().split()):
    pos1= i
    if word in stopwords:
        break

rest_text = txt.split()[pos1+1:]
print(rest_text)
# and now we do the same for pos2

for i,word in enumerate(rest_text):
    pos2= i
    if word in stopwords:
        print(word,pos2)
        break

rest_text = rest_text[:pos2]
print(rest_text)
```

I have to do this for thousands of texts and speed is important. looping is never the way to go in python.
But I can not come up with a list comprehension solution.

some help?

NOTE1: I made the example text longer to make clear the outcome
NOTE2:
other example:
txt = 'this is a **second text** to make clear the outcome that I like'
outcome: "second text"

Comment: *"looping is never the way to go in python"* - who said that? Anyway, one obvious improvement I can see in your current code is to make `stopwords` a `set` instead of a `list`.

Comment: a) @Marco Bonelli: I continously read that list comprehensions are better than loops. But I will made a comparison and post it.

Comment: b) @superb Now it does. There were a couple of typos. thanks for spot them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I can see might significantly improve performance here.

**`set` instead of `list`**

Your code must check whether some string is a member of `stopwords` a lot. A list is not the best data structure for this, since in the worst case, it requires a comparison with every element in the list. Membership test for a list is O(n).

`set`s are much quicker at performing this membership test. Their implementation in Python is something like a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which means they can perform the membership test in constant time, O(1). So, for large numbers of elements, a `set` will significantly outperform a `list` for this particular operation.

You can make a `set` of `stopwords`, instead of a list with:

```
stopwords = set(['a','the','with','etc'])
```

**`re.finditer` instead of `str.split()`**

If your `txt` is large, and you only require the first qualifying substring of your `txt` (as is implied in the question), then you may squeeze more performance by using `re.finditer` instead of `str.split()` to separate the words of your text.

`str.split()` returns a list of words from the entire text at once, whereas `re.finditer` returns an iterator that can yield words as they are needed. In the worst case you will obviously still need to 'loop' over the entire text, but if your matches are near the beginning of `txt`, time and memory savings may be significant.

For an example:

```
txt='A single house painted white with a few windows'
stopwords = set(['a','the','with','etc'])

import re

split_txt = (match.group(0) for match in re.finditer(r'\S+', txt))

result = []
word = next(split_txt)

while word.lower() in stopwords:
    word = next(split_txt)

while word.lower() not in stopwords:
    result.append(word)
    word = next(split_txt)

print(' '.join(result))
```

Note though that it is often better to just start out with some code that works to test on your input, than to prematurely start optimising. Testing will reveal whether optimisation is necessary. You say in the question that

> looping is never the way to go in Python

but this is just not true. Looping in one form or another is more often than not unavoidable, in any language. While the performance may not match that of compiled languages like C or Fortran, Python may surprise you with how performant it can be (if you let it)